# Is it necessary to emphasize a long history of an old saying?

Tags: word-usage

I understand the sentence "Give me a place to stand on, and I will move the Earth" is what Archimedes said about the Law of the Lever, which means the old saying has more than 2,000 years history.

Is it necessary to emphasize it is a proverb which has been recognized by so many people for so many years and say something like this?

> It is a quote that has been recognized for more than 2,000 years.

In other words, is it natural to say something like this?

> Archimedes said a famous proverb 2,000 years ago, that is, give me a place to stand on, and I will move the Earth.

Comment: It is not necessary, but you can if you wish. If you wanted you could cite it as <quote> - Archimedes c 250 BC or similar

Comment: What do you mean by 'is it necessary'? You can use a proverb on its own or, if you want to tell your readers something of its history, you can do so.